# Getting "attempt to index a nil value error" when attempting to create objects in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm putting some code into a module so I can draw and maintain multiple copies. I'm getting this common error but I can't see why. I understand what it's saying to a basic level, but as I'm able to see a print out from the table being created, I don't understand why calling a function that module contains would throw this error.

I've read through all the answers on SO, but I'm still at a loss. I've tried printing out at various stages to see where the issue is, everything works as if I had created an instance of the module, but the error persists.

Code below is cleaned of extraneous stuff.

```
local orbitalCircle = include('lib/orbital_circle')

function init()
  c1 = orbitalCircle.new(20, 42, 18, 1.7, 16, 62, 15, c1Sequence)
  <-- at this point print code from the module's init function works
  c1:doFunc(param)  <-- this will call the error
```

The module:

```
local Orbital_Circle = {}

-- set up variables
local some Vars Are here

function Orbital_Circle.new(x, y, diameter, scale_factor, number_of_notes, beats_per_second, frames_per_second, sequence_data)
    print("Orbital_Circle running")
end

function Orbital_Circle:doFunc(param)
    self.var = param  <-- I update a local var here
        print("self.var")  <-- I then print the updated number for sanity checking
end

return Orbital_Circle
```

I expect the var in my instance of this module to update and the functions code to run, but... no joy. I get the error.

Cheers.

Comment: Lua will give a file/line number for the error. What does it say? Do you have an 'n' variable somewhere?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm putting some code into a module so I can draw and maintain multiple copies.

I think there's a bit of a misunderstanding about how Lua modules work here. It's an easy mistake to make.

When you `require` a module in Lua, each subsequent `require` of the same file refers to the same code. So (eg) these two variables contain exactly the same code:

```lua
local orbitalCircle1 = require('lib/orbital_circle')
local orbitalCircle2 = require('lib/orbital_circle')
```

Which means that you can't use Lua modules by themselves to create OOP type objects as you are trying to do. Your `new` function must return something that can be used like an instance of a class, a unique table for each call:

```lua
local Orbital_Circle = {}

local shared_variable = 1

function Orbital_Circle.new(x, y)
  -- create unique table
  local obj = {}

  -- access these from table/object methods with self.xxx
  obj.x = x or 0
  obj.y = y or 0
  obj.var = "initial value"

  -- now define functions with an explicit 'self' parameter...
  function obj.doFunc(self, param)
    self.var = self.var .. " " .. param
    shared_variable = shared_variable + 1
  end

  -- ... or with the syntactic 'self' sugar, ':'
  function obj:printVars()
    print("self.var = " .. self.var)
    print("shared_variable = " .. shared_variable)
    print("self.x = " .. self.x)
  end

  return obj
end

return Orbital_Circle
```

You can also define the methods as `local function`s outside the `new` function that have `self` parameter and have a list of entries such as:

```
obj.anotherMethod = functionDeclaredAtTopOfFile
```

… to keep things tidier, if you like.

Comment: Amazing thank you. It's working. Lua is crazy, I am struggling to move from other languages to it. It'll happen :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely messed up.

`<--` will cause an error for unexpected symbol.

```
 c1 = orbitalCircle.new(20, 42, 18, 1.7, 16, 62, 15, c1Sequence)
```

will give you an error for indexing a global nil value c1 because `orbitalCircle.new` has no return value.

your init function is incomplete and you don't call it so the provided code does not do anything even if you fix the above errors.

The reported error is not caused by any line of code you provided here.

> Code below is cleaned of extraneous stuff.

I'm afraid you removed too much.

The error message tells you that you're indexing local `n`, a nil value from within a local function that has been defined in `n`'s scope.

This code for example:

```
local n
function test()
  local b = n.a
end
test()
```

would result in the error message:

```
input:3: attempt to index a nil value (upvalue 'n')
```

`n` is an upvalue for `test` because it is a local variable defined outside the functions body, but not a global variable.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback. I get that my code is a mess, I find Lua to be very peculiar and it's taking me longer to understand than I'd like. But... it's part of life right :)

Comment: @Tortex Lua is actually pretty easy. you'll learn it quickly. you should accept an answer that answers your question btw. not some random advice on something else you got wrong in your code. this might confuse others who come here later... your quesiton was why you get that particular error message. not how to implement OOP in Lua which btw was explained incorrectly or at least insufficiently by PaulR

Comment: @Piglet : you responded to the title whereas I employed a wider heuristic, engaging Tortex on the entirety of their post because they already knew what the error message meant: "I understand what it's saying...". So my answer is not "some random advice", it actually addressed the real issue whereas you did not. I also never claimed to provide the best/the only or even any specific OOP implementation, only code that works to solve the OPs problem. Which it does.

Comment: @PaulR No he said he doesn't know why he's getting this error and why calling a function would result in this error. that's what I explained to him. I mean what's the point of telling him to use require instead of include if the created objects don't share a common metatable... you gave him advise on how to improve parts of his code which were not even related to the posts topic. that's ok, but shouldn be accepted as the best answer. but I'm not here to argue and I don't care about the reputation I just wanted to avoid confusion by accepting answers that do not answer the question at hand.

Comment: @Piglet : I'm not saying you were wrong in choosing the angle you chose to reply to. I assessed that there was a mismatch between the title and content of the post, replied as such and have now rectified this by editing the title, the change for which has now been peer reviewed and approved.  Re the latest jab: "I mean what's the point of telling him to use require instead of include if the created objects don't share a common metatable.".. note that I included the common `shared_variable` to emphasise how the module system operates and how it can be leveraged for 'static' functionality.

Comment: @PaulR you just changed the error message to a completely different one... unfortunately peer review doesn't require any Lua knowledge. unless you completely mess up a post they'll approve anything that doesn't mean you were right to do so. the provided code in the edited question still does't cause that error message so what's the point of your edit?

Comment: @Piglet : I didn't change the error message to "a completely different one", I shortened it. "the provided code in the edited question still does't cause that error message so what's the point of"... answering to the error message instead of the content of the post? This is my point, thanks for agreeing with me. :)